# Solving an integral and then some...

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to write this:

$$ \int \frac{dy}{\left [ a+(c-a) (1-e^{by}) \right ]} = x $$

in an explicit form:

$$ y = f(x) $$

Some additional constrains are:

$$ x,y \in Re $$
$$ x,y > 0 $$
$$ a,b,c \in Re $$
$$ a,c > 0 $$
$$ b < 0 $$

I have tried using online integrators but I am having trouble including the additional constraints. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variable $\theta=e^{bx}$ leads to an integral easy to solve :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(c-a)(1-e^{bx})+a}$$ $$\Rightarrow \int\frac{dx}{(a-c)(e^{bx}-1)+a}$$ Substitute $u = bx$. We then get, $$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{b}\int \frac{1}{(a-c)e^u+c} du...(1)$$ Now substitute $v =\frac{1}{(a-c)e^u + c}$. We then get $\frac{dv}{du} = -\frac{(a-c)e^u}{((a-c)e^u+c))^2}$.
Also, $e^{-u} = \frac{a-c}{\frac{1}{v}-c}$. Thus, $(1)$ becomes $$\int \frac{1}{cv-1} dv$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{\ln(cv-1)}{c}$$ Now substitute the required values to get your integral. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but I am still having trouble getting an explicit formula for y=f(x) for the relevant a,b,c from this solution to the integral. Any suggestions?

Comment: Three things to keep in mind: 1) he wrote this integral with $x$, but yours with with $y$, so your last substitution should be $u=by$, 2) don't forget your constant of integration, and 3) start with his expression + C = x, solve for v, then substitute in what v is in terms of u, then solve for u and substitute in what u is in terms of y.